# load multiple files into oracle table with talend open studio

Tags: oracle, talend

I am using the tOracleOutputBulkExec component in a job to transfer data from a list of files  to an Oracle database.

The job works fine if I hard code the control file location in advance setting for tOracleOutputBulkExec but I want to softcode the location to a database table.

To do this, I use a global variable to indicate the location of my file but the control file is generated dynamically by the component tOracleOutputBulk met the fields of the tables between two cotes like that "field1" that's why when I run my job I have this error 
the "col1" doesn't exist in the table:

> SQL*Loader-466: La colonne "col1" n'existe pas dans la table .
>   Exception in component tOracleOutputBulkExec_1_tOBE
>   java.lang.Exception

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to try and clean it up a bit but I'm unsure what you mean by: `tOracleOutputBulk met the fields of the tables between two cotes like that "field1"`. Can you post a screenshot of your job so we can see more easily what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks ydaetskcoR fro your reply, in my job i use tfileList--->tfileinputdelimited--> toracleoutputbulkexec , when i run my job I have this error : SQL * Loader-466: The column "Idx" does not exist in the table KPI.CNX_ODS. 
Exception in component tOracleOutputBulkExec_1_tOBE 
java.lang.Exception

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere along the way your schema is getting messed up and is missing your additional data. Check the schema of your tOracleOutputBulkExec and make sure there is a column for the additional global variable data. If there isn't there is not a way to create this directly with a bulkexe.

Comment: Thanks mw90 for your reply, I have my  totally shcema in the component toracleoutputbulkexec but without the double cotes " ", have you any idea how to resolve it ?